# Как на vue.js поменять стили элемента при клике на него?

Tags: css, vue.js

Нужно чтобы при клике элемент выделялся другими стилями.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clicked: false
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div_clicked {
  background-color: #020202;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-on:click="clicked = !clicked" v-bind:class="{'div_clicked': clicked}">Click on me</div>
```